# How do I convert translate this Picasso code into Glide?

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide

So, I am writing an Android application based on this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCCCLcD4xbY) as a reference, and right now, I have reached the ImageAdapter part. Since I want to use Glide instead of Picasso, I would like to change this line

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + array.get(position)).
                    resize(width, (int)(width*1.5)).placeholder(d).into(imageView);
```

into its Picasso equivalent.

You can also see the complete ImageAdapter code here to make things clearer: http://pastebin.com/K7ZCwqid

Comment: And what exactly is causing you difficulty?

Comment: This is my first time using both libraries.

Comment: Besides, I know there are some portions from the tutorial (not just this part, but also the other parts) that need to be changed to match with the more modern environment of both Android and Android Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Glide.with(mContext)
    .load("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + array.get(position))
    .override(width, (int)(width*1.5))
    .placeholder(d)
    .into(imageView);
```